# How do you find the most common words in multiple files in unix?

Tags: linux, unix, grep, printf

I have 3 files in my current directory and I need to find the overall most frequent word. How do I do that? I am only able to find the most frequent word from each of the files:

```
$ for file in *; do 
    printf '%s : %s\n' "$(grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]]+' "$file" | sort | uniq -c | 
        sort -rn | head -n1)" "$file" 
done
```

Comment: `cat file1 file2 file3 | {grep/sort/uniq pipe}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate all the files into a single stream and use the same pipeline:

```
cat * | grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]]+' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | sed 1q
```